# Prevent creating definition files `d.ts` onstorybook build (Vite react library Project)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, vite, package.json

I'm working on a component's library using react + typescript . I'm using vite and each time I build storybook, dts plugin runs.

That has 2 side effects:

- It creates a lot of unnecessary folders and files
- Takes extra time the CI build step

This is my `vite.config.ts`

```js
import { defineConfig } from "vite"
import { resolve } from "path"
import dts from "vite-plugin-dts"
import { viteStaticCopy } from "vite-plugin-static-copy"

export default defineConfig({
  publicDir: false,
  build: {
    lib: {
      entry: resolve(__dirname, "src/index.ts"),
      name: "kb-lib",
      fileName: "index",
    },
    rollupOptions: {
      external: ["react"],
      output: {
        globals: {
          react: "React",
        },
        assetFileNames: "static/styles/components.css",
      },
    },
  },
  plugins: [
    dts({
      insertTypesEntry: true,
    }),
    viteStaticCopy({
      targets: [
        {
          src: resolve(__dirname, "src/static"),
          dest: "./",
        },
        {
          src: resolve(__dirname, "./README.md"),
          dest: "./",
          rename: "README.md",
        },
        {
          src: resolve(__dirname, "./package.json"),
          dest: "./",
        },
      ],
    }),
  ],
})
```

Here are the extra folders/files it creates:

[image]

I wanna prevent the creation of `.d.ts` files on storybook building.

Is there a way to prevent this behavior?

Comment: Why can't you just remove `dts(...)` from `plugins: [ dts(...) ]` ?

Comment: See https://storybook.js.org/docs/react/builders/vite#configuration

Comment: @Dimava I had a build step to create the library to publish to NPM that uses that plugin to create `d.ts` definition files.

Also, I don't understand when you put the docs. I read it before, but I didn't find a solution for this.

Comment: you can `viteFinal(config){ config.plugins.shift(); return config; }` as far as I undestood

Comment: Thanks @Dimava

I solved this removing `dts` plugin and moving the definitons generation to the tsc. This way I decoupled `d.ts` generation from Vite.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[UPDATED] I solved this removing `dts` plugin and moving the definitions generation to the `npm run tsc` script.

This way I decoupled d.ts generation from Vite and can have both working together.

Answer (score 2):

Add in your .storybook/main.js|ts this:

```
import { withoutVitePlugins } from '@storybook/builder-vite'
...
const config: StorybookConfig = {
    ...
    async viteFinal(config) {
        return {
            ...config,
            plugins: await withoutVitePlugins(config.plugins, ['vite:dts']),
        }
    },
}
```